# How to code C# MVC model for many to many join table for sqlite database migration { edited }

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, sqlite, many-to-many

I am creating a sqlite database to track users assigned to teams. This would mean many-to-many table relationship. I need help making the model for the migration.

```
users table: 
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserTeam> UserTeams { get; set; }
    }

team table:
    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserTeam> UserTeams{ get; set; }
    }

UserTeam Table:
    public class UserTeam
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId{ get; set; }
        public Team Team{ get; set; }  
        public int TeamId{ get; set; } //... I have this one for owner of the team
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }

DataContext:
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base (options) {}

        public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserTeam>()
                .HasKey(ut => new { ut.UserId, ut.TeamId });  
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserTeam>()
                .HasOne(ut => ut.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.UserTeams)
                .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId);  
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserTeam>()
                .HasOne(ut => ut.Team)
                .WithMany(t => t.UserTeams)
                .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.TeamId);
        }
    }
```

From what I read declaring I ICollection on team class and user class would force a join table creating. However when I try to migrate, I get this message: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'User.Teams' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Any suggestions on how to correctly make join tables in sqlite would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are using `EF Core 2.x`. It is necessary to define the entity in the model. This means you will have to define relationship by overriding it in the `OnModelCreating` method.

I would further normalize your structure by creating another table to hold the reference for the user and the team the user belongs to and vice-versa. I would call this table `UserTeam` (for the lack of better naming)

So I will have something like:

```
public class User
{
    //....omitted
    public virtual ICollection<UserTeam> UserTeams { get; set; }
}

public class UserTeam
{      
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int TeamId{ get; set; }
    public Team Team{ get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    //.... omitted
    public virtual ICollection<UserTeam> UserTeams{ get; set; }
}
```

The UserTeam table will need to be configured so that EFCore can map it successfully. This is where we define the many-to-many relationship

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTeam>()
        .HasKey(ut => new { ut.UserId, ut.TeamId });  
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTeam>()
        .HasOne(ut => ut.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserTeams)
        .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId);  
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTeam>()
        .HasOne(ut => ut.Team)
        .WithMany(t => t.UserTeams)
        .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.TeamId);
}
```

Comment: Thank You! What file does the OnModelCreating go into? Can't seem to find if I need to make a new class or put it into DbContext or somewhere else.

Comment: That is an overridable method from `DbContext` class imported from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package. So, correct it should go to where your application context is.  You should have a context class that extends `DbContext`, just put it in there :)

Comment: I edited my question. Is this how it's supposed to look? The migration ran but just wanted to make sure. Super green at C#. And you didn't mean Db context as in this DbContext?     public class DbContext : IDisposable, IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>, IDbContextDependencies, IDbSetCache, IDbQueryCache, IDbContextPoolable

Comment: @tonsar yes exactly how you have it in your edited/updated question. Hope this helps :)